# image preloading problem (using $("img").load())

Tags: jquery

I use the load function to preload Images before applying a hover effect.

```
$("img").load(function(){ //image preloading

//some function & variable setting

    $listingItems.hover(
        function(){
            //effect
        },
        function(){
            //effect back
        }
    )

}) // load
```

the problem i have i that the effects only works if i reload the page. When i first come to the page, the images are loaded but there is no hover effect.

You can take a look at the source here:
http://meodai.ch/rundum/shop.html

What have i done wrong? Can anyone help? Is there an other simple way to preload images before executing a function?

Comment: I had the same problem for my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` event won't fire if the image comes from cache in some browsers, but there's a work-around for this by checking the `.complete` property and using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to make sure the `load` event handler only fires once, like this:

```
$("img").one('load', function(){
  //current code
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

This loops though the images, if they're `.complete` (either loaded *really* fast or from cache) it triggers the `load` event handler, if it already ran (the *really* fast load case), not sweat, that's what the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is for.